# Breadth First Search on an Array of Linked Lists [edited / shortened with error]

Tags: java, search, graph, linked-list, breadth-first-search

I am studying how in a small world (undirected graph) how long range connections can shorten the path length between any given to nodes. Basically I have an array of linked lists. Each section in the array is linked to the 1st and 2nd neighbors on either side, then some random connections are implemented (Making an adjacency list).

now i have to do a BFS on each spot in the array to see how many moves it takes to get from a spot in the array to another.

so for example this is what the firt 9 spots of the array look like

```
[1, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 7, 8, 114]
[5, 6, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 9, 10]
[7, 8, 10, 11]
```

as you can see spot 0 in the array is adjacent to 1 and 2 since there is nothing on the other side. Spot 6 has one of the long range connections to spot 114.

This is my attempt at bfs amd im getting some errors. First of all how do you think it looks? but im getting a null pointer exception on the line

```
u = q.remove();
```

a null pointer exception.Any idea why? What u should be equal to now is 1. but idk why it wont work. i did some print outs to see if it was working or not and after the addAll the q = [1, 2] so when i did the printout q.remove = 1, but for some reason now its stopping my program!

```
public static int bfs(List<Integer>[] smallWorld, int start){

    int distance = 0;
    int size = smallWorld.length;

    //for each location in smallWorld do a bfs to every other location      
    int u;
    int white = 0, grey = 1, black = 2;
    int [] color, d, pie;
    Queue <Integer> q = new <Integer> LinkedList();

    color = new int [size];
    d = new int [size];
    pie = new int [size];

    for( int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        color[x] = white;
        d[x] = -1;
        pie[x] = -1;
    }

    color[start] = grey;
    d[start] = 0;
    pie[start] = -1;
    q.addAll(smallWorld[start]);        //enqueue the adjacent items
    while(q != null){
        u = q.remove();
        for(int v = 0; v < smallWorld[u].size(); v++){      //for every vertex u is adjacent to
            if(color[v] == white){
                color[v] = grey;
                d[v] = d[u] + 1;
                pie[v] = u;
                q.addAll(smallWorld[v]);
            }
        }
        color[u] = black;
    }


    return distance;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Why not use a debugger to step through your code and see what's wrong?

Comment: that doesnt explain why its wrong, but its okay i sloved it by simply putting while(!isEmpty()) instead of q !=null